# EXEC Query With FOR XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
:XML ON
EXEC sp_helprolemember FOR XML PATH, ROOT ('ResultSetData'),BINARY BASE64;
```

It throws me an error when the above query is executed stating incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for' in sql.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can add FOR XML to a exec proc command. You must create a temporary table, insert into the temporary table the result of the procedure and finally select from tamporary table using FOR XML.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would work around it:

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE(DbRole     VARCHAR(20)
                 , MemberName VARCHAR(20)
                 , MemberSID  VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @Results
EXEC sp_helprolemember 'your role name herer';

SELECT *
FROM   @Results
FOR XML PATH, ROOT('your root name here'), BINARY BASE64;
```